# Password based encryption using AES in java 5 (JCE only)

Tags: java, security, aes, jce

I would like to use AES (192 or 256 bits), but am stuck on how to generate a key from a user supplied password.

I have gone [through this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption), and am able to run the program in Java 6. However, I need to run the same program in Java 5, and SecretKeyFactory for PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 is not available in JDK 5.

So, essentially, I need to generate 192 or 256 bits for a SecretKey based on users password, and I would like a secure way to do that in java 5.

Help appreciated!

EDIT #1
Just to avoid getting stuck, I am now using 128 bits from MD5(user-entered-password + fixed-salt) as the key to AES. I know it sucks, and will change it the moment I figure out a good way to generate the key.

Comment: It might help if you post the code you have that works in Java6.

Comment: @Jim - see accepted answer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992019/java-256bit-aes-encryption. The code works perfect in JDK6, but I am out of ideas trying to get it work for JDK 5

Comment: So grab the code from a higher Java version 1.5 and create your own API, or do likewise using Bouncy Castle. Can't be that hard.

Answer (score -2):

Is there a reason you want PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1?

SecretKeyFactory existed in 1.4.2, so you might look [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html).

Comment: SecretKeyFactory existed in 1.4.2, but it doesn't implement the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 algorithm. The link you pasted uses KeyFactory to generate keys, which is not suitable for my purposes. I need to generate a key from a password using some sort of key distribution function -- but I can't find a good way to do it in JDK 5